# Tomcat Jdbc Connection Pool active connection

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, cron, tomcat-jdbc

We have a spring-boot application which uses embedded tomcat for deployment and **default** tomcat-jdbc connection pooling with MySQL back-end with no customization for MySQL or Tomcat side. 
The app has a few schedulers that runs mostly during specific time in a day i.e. between the last cron run yesterday and 1st cron runs today, there is more than **9 hrs** of gap. However, whenever the cron ran earlier, it has never come across idle connection issue. 
Nowadays we see an error message 
`The last packet successfully received from the server was XXXXXXXX milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was XXXXXXXY milliseconds ago.`
I can always try using **testOnBorrow** with **validateQuery** adn/or **testWhileIdle** etc as reqd to get this working but...
I'm trying to understand the *lifecycle of the active connection* in tomcat-jdbc connection pooling. Acc to the documentation, the default value for `wait_timeout` for MySQL is **8 hrs**, whereas default for `idle_connection_timeout` on Tomcat_jdbc is nearly **6 secs**.

1. If the default value is in use everywhere, then why issue has never surfaced before?
2. Or is it something that the connections in the tomcat-jdbc connection pool are made active every time the *cron* starts running and becomes idle thereafter?
3. Is it the state of the spring-boot app or the scheduler that makes any difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not in configuration or setup. `spring-boot` app uses `spring-data` lib which makes use of the underlying `connection pool`. The pool handles the connection(s) as per the connection pool implementation. The use of `@Transactional` however decides when the underlying connection is opened. If there is none specified in `spring-boot` app the default implementation of `spring-data` opens it during crud operations; else it is opened during the method call in application annotated with `@Transactional`.

In my case it was the latter.. After opening the connection a time taking non DB process was running which was making the connection to go idle after opening and was throwing exception while actually using it later.